# Why isn't my last instruction taking precedence? CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is my CSS source code

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #42455a;
}

.menu ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 50px;
}

.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
    color: #b2b1b1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.logo img {
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    margin-right: 48px;
}

.active {
    color: #19dafa !important;
}

.search {
    margin-left: 398px; /* problem in this line */
}
```

I have a ul full of li's, and I set their properties in the ".menu ul li {}" category. The thing is I don't want ALL of them to have the same properties, I want the last one which is a search bar to be all the way on the right, like so:

" - - - - ___________ -"

where each "-" represents an li and the "_" is the space in between. The problem is in the very last category I made the margin-left 398 pixels. But despite that being the last instruction it is still following the instructions set before.

When I use !important it works, but I don't see why I would need to use it when supposedly the final instruction takes precedence?

The problem also applies in the .active class as well. Why do I have to use the !important to get it to work? Seems like a hassle if I have to use !important everytime I want a unique property in one of my elements.

EDIT:
I ended up finding a work-around by typing:

```
.search {
    right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

but my question still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final rule in your CSS does not take precedence. The various selectors of a CSS rule combine to form a *specificity* number which is what determines which CSS rules are applied. Classes, tag names, IDs, and other element attributes each increase the specificity score of a rule -- the more selectors, the more specific the rule.

You add together all of the specificity weightings and can essentially read it like a 4-digit number. For example, using a tag gives +1 while a class gives +10 (this isn't totally accurate, see reading materials at end). So your rule for `.search` has a specificity of 10 since it's just a class, while your rule `.menu ul` is 11 since it's a class with a tag. When applied to the same matching elements, the properties defined in `.menu ul` will take precedence over `.search` despite `.search` being written last.

`!important` essentially acts like a boolean flag to work regardless of the specificity scores. However, two rules with `!important` flags will still fall back to specificity. Similarly, if two rules have the same specificity, *only then* does the last one written take precedence.

For further reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: Bruh thanks a lot. I swear I heard somewhere that priority goes to the last rule. I guess they meant assuming you had the same tags. Thanks for breaking it down for me, appreciate it.